# randomly uninstalled apps from sd card

Tags: applications, sd-card, uninstallation

Lately I've noticed that some apps get constantly uninstalled from my sd card. I figured it had to do with little free space left but apparently I had almost 3 GB left and after monitoring for a couple of days. The apps that get uninstalled like this are not the most space consuming ones, after all; looks completely random to me but starts to get really annoying. I think it started about the same time some apps and/or their icons disappeared from the home screen (not from the phone though) - but that was some Google issue I think. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.